# How would I stop the loop when after its added the names to the list and other errors

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, validation, subroutine

How would I stop my code looping after it has added the amount of names the user has inputted instead of doing this:

1. Add Name
2. Show list
3. Quit

Enter your choice : 1

How many names would you like to enter: 2 # How would I set a max of 10 names here?

Enter name: Bob

Enter name: Jim

How many names would you like to enter: # How would I stop this line from repeating?

Actual code:

```
names = []
def displayMenu():
    print(" 1. Add Name")
    print(" 2. Show list")
    print(" 3. Quit")
    choice = int(input("Enter your choice : "))
    while choice >5 or choice <1:
        choice = input("Invalid. Re-enter your choice: ")
    return choice

def addname():
    while True:
        number=int(input('How many names would you like to enter: '))
        name = [input('Enter name:') for _ in range(number)]
        names.append(name)

def displayData():
    #name.split(",") how would i correctly user split here
    print(names) 

option = displayMenu()

while option != 3:
    if option == 1:
       addname()
    elif option == 2:
        displayData()
    option = displayMenu()

print("Program terminating")
```

Comment: First off, why are you allowing 4 and 5 as menu options when you only have 3? Also, when you put a statement inside a loop, it runs with every iteration of the loop, do you really mean to ask for the number of name every time you get a name from the user?

Comment: SO is not a substitution to people not wanting to lean basics of programming. 
If you can write a loop, may be you should revisit a book or a tutor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, first off, since you only have three menu options, this line:

```
while choice >5 or choice <1:
```

Should look like this:

```
while 3 < choice < 1:
```

So your displayMenu function looks like this:

```
names = []
def displayMenu():
    print(" 1. Add Name")
    print(" 2. Show list")
    print(" 3. Quit")
    choice = int(input("Enter your choice : "))
    while 3 < choice < 1: # Only accept choices in between 3 and 1
        choice = input("Invalid. Re-enter your choice: ")
    return choice
```

You also said that your addname function was looping forever, this is because you have an infinite while loop.

What you need, as @ettanany said, is a for loop:

> In your case, `for` loop would work also:
>
> ```
> def addname():
>     number = int(input('How many names would you like to enter: '))
>     for i in range(number):
>         name = input('Enter name: ')
>         names.append(name)
> ```

What this does is ask the user how many names he wants to enter, and then runs the code inside the loop for that amount of times -- so if the user enters the number 9, it will ask for 9 names.

You also said that there should be a maximum of 10 names. We can use a while loop like you did in the displayMenu function to make sure the user enters a number that is 10 or below:

```
def addname():
    number = int(input('How many names would you like to enter: '))
    while number > 10: # Don't allow any numbers under 10
        number = int(input('Please enter a number under 10: '))
    for i in range(number):
        name = input('Enter name: ')
        names.append(name)
```

Finally, in your displayData function, you want to 'split' the names and print them out.

Just doing `print(names)` would give us a result like this:

```
[ 'Spam', 'Eggs', 'Waheed' ]
```

If we want it to look nice, we need to use a for loop.

```
for name in names:
    print( name ) # You can change this line to print( name, end=' ' ) 
                  # If you want all the names on one line.
```

This will yield a result like this:

```
Spam
Eggs
Waheed
```

Which looks much better than just printing out the list.

Complete (fixed) code:

```
names = []
def displayMenu():
    print(" 1. Add Name")
    print(" 2. Show list")
    print(" 3. Quit")
    choice = int(input("Enter your choice : "))
    while 3 < choice < 1: # Only accept choices in between 3 and 1
        choice = input("Invalid. Re-enter your choice: ")
    return choice

def addname():
    number = int(input('How many names would you like to enter: '))
    while number > 10: # Don't allow any numbers under 10
        number = int(input('Please enter a number under 10: '))
    for i in range(number):
        name = input('Enter name: ')
        names.append(name)

def displayData():
    for name in names:
        print( name ) # You can change this line to print( name, end=' ' ) 
                      # If you want all the names on one line.

option = displayMenu()

while option != 3:
    if option == 1:
       addname()
    elif option == 2:
        displayData()
    option = displayMenu()

print("Program terminating")
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `while True`, you need to use `while i < number`, so your `addname()` function should be as follows:

```
def addname():
    i = 0
    number = int(input('How many names would you like to enter: '))
    while i < number:
        name = input('Enter name: ')  # We ask user to enter names one by one
        names.append(name)
        i += 1
```

In your case, `for` loop would work also:

```
def addname():
    number = int(input('How many names would you like to enter: '))
    for i in range(number):
        name = input('Enter name: ')
        names.append(name)
```